# Set variables to initial value

Tags: angular, variables

Is there a way to restore variables  value to initial value? I have like 40 variables in total declared and after save() I need to reset every variable, example:

```
client = ''; select = '0'; products = [];

constructor(private http: Http){}

save(objSave){
  this.http.post('url', objSave).subscribe(data => this.clearFields());
}

clearFields(){
  this.client = '';
  this.select = '0';
  this.products = [];
}
```

But I'm looking for a more efficient or shorter way to do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What you should do is store the variables in a class, and reinstantiate it once to reinitialize the variables.

Comment: That's what I tought of doing, just was hoping to get another solution

Comment: You could create a function that initialize all your variables, and use the same function when your data needs a reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible work-around for this with [Lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) is:

Define your initial variable values as fields of a holding object

```
defaultVariables: any = {
  client: '', 
  select: '0',
  products: []
}
workingVariables: any;
```

Don't touch that object, use `_.cloneDeep` to create a clone of it and start working on the cloned object:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

ngOnInit() {
  this.workingVariables = _.cloneDeep(this.defaultVariables);
}
```

Then in your `clearFields` function, reset the data by using `_.cloneDeep` again:

```
clearFields(){
  this.workingVariables = _.cloneDeep(this.defaultVariables);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Harry's answer is good :) Just wanted to present that you can do this without lodash, just use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead. Here's a sample using Harry's codesample with some changes:

```ts
defaultVariables: any = {
  client: '', 
  select: '0',
  products: []
}

workingVariables: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.workingVariables = Object.assign({}, this.defaultVariables)
}

clearFields(){
  this.workingVariables = Object.assign({}, this.defaultVariables)
}
```